# Wordpress: unable to connect to wp-admin (localhost can't provide a secure connection?)

Tags: wordpress, apache, localhost, mamp

I've got a MAMP (version 6.3) localhost using Apache running on a Mac Mini locally and i am in final testing before publishing a new plugin that i've created.  I popped my plugin into my plugins directory (as i will when i go into production) and suddenly, I am unable to access wp-admin to look at Wordpress (as in 'localhost:8888/wp-admin).  Localhost access works just fine (as in 'localhost:8888'), but when attempting to enter wp-admin, the page fails to be served up with the following messages:

"This site can't provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

I cannot find ANY information that will help me find a solution.  There is nothing in the Apache logs at all.  I've got debugging set up and running on my site and there's nothing in there at all.  I literally have NO idea how to proceed in finding the problem.  I get the same messages in either Chrome or Safari.

I've searched this error and it seems it could be a few things, but the source seems to be a bad certificate or something.  If so, i don't know how to correct that condition.  IF my understanding is correct, localhost doesn't even require SSL (?), so even the "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" is confusing.

Another suggestion that i've found is to disable your plugins folder by renaming it to essentially invalidate ALL plugins.  I've tried that as well, no change in the error message that i am receiving.

Can anyone provide any concrete steps for how to resolve this so that i can get into the wp-admin facility on localhost?  I admit that i know "not much" about certificates and SSL and the like.  I literally don't know where to start.
thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about _configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It fits better on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com, or on serverfault, following the Apache httpd tag description's guidance.

Comment: Olaf, i was not aware of the wordpress.stackexchange.com site and perhaps you are correct.  I am happy to have this closed and i will post it there.  My apologies for coming to the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

request via http, something like this

http://localhost:8888/wp-admin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion MikeMoy, i tried that and got "Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server".  This is to bypass https, correct?

Comment: What url do you normally type to access wp-admin

Comment: "localhost:8888/wp-admin". I never preface it with either "https://" or "http://".  I assume it defaults to one of those two?

Comment: Depends on the browser you are using, Google Chrome will try request via https by default if you do not specify http.

Comment: so did you request h ttp://localhost:8888/wp-admin ?

Comment: Yes i have.  Regardless of which browser i use, when i enter "http://localhost:8888/wp-admin" (Safari or Chrome), the browser changes "http" to "https".  I've tried a few things (all of which have not worked) that i will update in the original post on the thread.

Comment: You can request http on Google chrome by prefixing with http, I have done it many times.

Answer (score -1):

open your wp-config.php file and add this online

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false );
```

save the wp-config.php file. You can add just above this line

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

Now try opening your localhost this should work.